# What is the internal hom functor for vector spaces?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, category-theory, additive-categories

I am wondering what the explicit definition of the internal hom functor $[X,\_]$ (described in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3176027/difference-between-internal-hom-and-exponential-objects/3176048)), for the category of vector spaces $\text{Vect}$ (over, say, the field of real numbers) is.

I am guessing that $\text{Vect} \overset{[X,\_]}{\longrightarrow} \text{Vect}.$ I am guessing that for a vector space $Y$ we have that $[X,Y]$ has elements as linear maps $\phi$ from $X$ to $Y,$ and $X\overset{\phi + \phi'}{\rightarrow}Y$ sends $x \in X$ to $\phi(x)+\phi'(x)\in Y.$ Also, I guess for a scaler $\lambda,$ we have $X\overset{\lambda. \phi }{\rightarrow}Y$ sends $x \in X$ to $\lambda. \phi(x)\in Y.$

Is the above correct ? If not what should it be ?

The main thing I am wondering is how the functor $[X,\_]$ works on arrows. In other words, if I have a linear map $A \overset{\psi}{\rightarrow} B$ then how is the linear map $[X,A] \overset{[X,\psi]}{\longrightarrow} [X,B]$ defined ?

It would be really great if the answer could be as explicit and simple as possible (i.e., avoiding mention of tensors, adjunctions, modules etc.) as I am not well versed in linear or abstract algebra.

Comment: There is really only one possible definition of the map $[X,A] \to [X,B]$. Writing down these "only possible" definitions from (linear) algebra is a prerequisite for doing category theory. You say that "I am not well versed in linear or abstract algebra", but then it is better to learn that first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am guessing that for a vector space $Y$ we have that $[X,Y]$ has elements as linear maps $\phi$ from $X$ to $Y,$ and $X\overset{\phi + \phi'}{\rightarrow}Y$ sends $x \in X$ to $\phi(x)+\phi'(x)\in Y.$ Also, I guess for a scaler $\lambda,$ we have $X\overset{\lambda. \phi }{\rightarrow}Y$ sends $x \in X$ to $\lambda. \phi(x)\in Y.$

yes, this is correct.

> The main thing I am wondering is how the functor $[X,\_]$ works on arrows. In other words, if I have a linear map $A \overset{\psi}{\rightarrow} B$ then how is the linear map $[X,A] \overset{[X,\psi]}{\longrightarrow} [X,B]$ defined?

The answer really depends on your background, at this point; if you want an intuitive argument, the functor $[X,\_]$ acts as post-composition by $\psi$; this is a map of vector spaces, if you define the structure as above: for the sake of brevity, let's call $[X,\psi]=\psi_*$ (this is a common notation); then, $\psi_*(\alpha) = \psi\circ\alpha$, and (since this equation is true elementwise) $\psi_*(\alpha+\beta)=\psi_*(\alpha) + \psi_*(\beta)$, and similarly with scalar multiplication.

A more elaborate, conceptual argument requires what you want to avoid: adjunctions between categories.