# Currying in the category of topological pairs

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, category-theory, monoidal-categories

Let's denote by $ \mathsf{Top}(2) $ the category of [topological pairs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_pair). That is, let $ \mathsf{Top}(2) $ be the category whose objects are all the pairs $ (X,A) $ where $ X $ is a topological space [*] and $ A\subset X $, and whose maps $ f\colon (X,A)\to (Y,B) $ are the continuous functions $ f\colon X\to Y $ such that $ f(A)\subset B $.

Let's define
$$
\left[(X,A),(Y,B)\right] = \left(\hom_{\mathsf{Top}(2)}((X,A),(Y,B)),\hom_{\mathsf{Top}(2)}((X,X),(Y,B))\right)
$$
for every pair of pairs $ (X,A) $ and $ (Y,B) $ and
$$
[f,g](\alpha) = g\circ\alpha\circ f
$$
for every $ f\colon (X^\prime,A^\prime)\to (X,A) $ and $ g\colon (Y,B)\to (Y^\prime,B^\prime) $.

I've read that if we want something like the [tensor-hom adjunction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor-hom_adjunction) for $ R $-modules ($ R $ a commutative ring) to hold in $ \mathsf{Top}(2) $ (where $ \left[{-},{-}\right] $ is the right "internal" hom functor), we should define a "tensor" product between pairs as
$$
(X,A)\boxplus (Y,B) = (X\times Y,{(A\times Y)}\cup {(X\times B)})\text{.}
$$

In other words, given a pair $ (X,A) $, with this definition of $ (Y,B)\boxplus (X,A) $ it should be possible to prove that there is an adjunction
$$
{-}\boxplus {(X,A)} \dashv \left[(X,A),{-}\right]
$$
where $ {-}\boxplus {(X,A)} $ acts on $ g\colon (Y,B)\to (Y^\prime,B^\prime) $ by $ g\boxplus {(X,A)} = g\times 1_X $.

My categorical understanding of basic mathematical facts a bit shaky. Just to say, until some five minutes ago I never properly realized how the aforementioned tensor-hom adjunction that one learns in a abstract algebra course is "of a different nature" than the adjunction that defines the exponential object $ Y^X $ of $ X $ and $ Y $ in an arbitrary category [**].

Nevertheless, I would really like to learn more about tensor (monoidal) products, internal homs, closed categories, exponentials and all that, and I'm a learn-by-example kind of person, so I would really appreciate an explanation of the previous claims using those big words.

Phrased differently, I'm asking why in Algebraic Topology we define $ (X,A)\boxplus (Y,B) $ the way we do it, and in what sense this definition is dictated by a categorical imperative.

---

[*] More properly, suppose that all the topological spaces appearing are "[nice](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/convenient+category+of+topological+spaces)" spaces.

[**]This [pair](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3176048) of [posts](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1121829/tensor-products-from-internal-hom?rq=1) clarified something, but I am still in a phase where detailed proof and explanations are really appreciated.

Comment: If $\boxplus$ is to make the category of pairs closed monoidal, you need to specify what the monoidal product is here. Do you mean to ask, "is/why is $\boxplus$ an internal hom for the product pairing $(X,A)\times(Y,B):=(X\times Y,A\times B)$?"

Comment: It seems to me that in this case we "know" how to give an "internal hom functor" (whatever this means), and we would like to come up with a monoidal product such that something like the tensor-hom adjunction holds. And this product "must" be $ {\boxplus} $. But I'm not able to do all of this alone at the moment.

Comment: It's not clear to me whether you want $\boxplus$ to be the left or right adjoint in this setup, or what you think the internal hom / product should be. There should be more context to create a tensor-hom adjunction analogue

Comment: I guess that ${-}\boxplus (X,A) : \hom_{\mathsf{Top}(2)}((X,A),{-}) = {-}\otimes_R M : \hom_R(M,{-})$ intends to say that both operations behave similarly. You should not use "=" here.

Comment: I heavily edited the question. I hope it is more clear now!